# AngularJS Material mdDialog and display locals in a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controlleras, angularjs-material

Part of the controller which spawn `mdDialog` looks like

```
$scope.removeAttendee = function(item) {

    console.log(item);

    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'views/removeMsg.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
        locals: {item: item}
    })
```

and controller for `mdDialog`:

```
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

    var attendee = this;

    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    $scope.save = function(response) {
        $mdDialog.hide(response);
    };

    $scope.remove = function(response) {
        $mdDialog.hide(response);
    };

}
```

`removeMsg.tmpl.html` has that code

```
<p>You are going to remove {{ ctrl.item.firstName }} {{ ctrl.item.lastName }} from the lunch list.</p>
```

But I'm not able to display related values even when I will change code to something simple like

```
locals { item: "test" }
```

and related part to

```
{{ ctrl.item }}
```

Any suggestions why I'm not getting display those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `DialogController` with `controllerAs` alias, you should assign resolved value to controller context `item` variable

```
function DialogController($scope,$mdDialog,item){//Item value will resolve via locals
    var attendee = this;
    attendee.item = item; // this line is important.

    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    $scope.save = function(response) {
        $mdDialog.hide(response);
    };

    $scope.remove = function(response) {
        $mdDialog.hide(response);
    };
}
```

Apart from this, please shift `$scope` methods to use `attendee`(this). As `controllerAs` pattern doesn't encourage to use `$scope` in controller.

Comment: Just figured that the same time that I can't reuse `DialogController` defined for another dialog box as I need to pass `item` to it.

Comment: Not sure what was version of AngularJS material for $mdDialog , but as per docs here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#javascript-promise-api-syntax-custom-dialog-template
you shouldn't need to Inject variable to DialogController function.
So you can reuse DialogController .

Comment: @ChaitanyaBabar you're right, as per OP, it uses `locals: {item: item}` that means `item` has to be injected inside application, I'm not recommending to use it for everywhere. I know there are alternative ways to make it more elegant. I believe if controller function re-usability think would make this far away from what OP has asked. Anyways, thanks for heads up though.